# Combining two shapefiles with different map projections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, epsg

I collected point data in `EPSG:26909` in QField when it was supposed to be in `EPSG:26910`. Now I have one shapefile with a different projection and I want to change it to `EPSG 26910` and combine the shapefiles in QGIS.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the 'reproject layer' tool on the layer you want to change.  Or, if you just need to reassign the projection without reprojecting the data, then use the 'assign projection' tool.

If your data is currently showing up in the wrong location, you need the 'assign projection' tool.  If your data is showing up in the correct location, you need the 'reproject layer' tool.

Both tools are in the processing toolbox under 'Vector general'

Comment: Thank-you so much! So easy!:)

Comment: Sweet!  Do you mind accepting the answer so this question doesn't show up as unanswered?  There is a futile effort here to keep the unanswered questions to a minimum :)

Comment: thanks! I think I did but let me know if it didn't work.